# Is there any utility to the so-common case of merely serving a React class as a web-app, without the boilerplate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose you define a whole web-app as a React class:

```
const myWebApp = React.createClass({...})
```

That is, no CSS, no routes, just a flat SPA out of a React class. Suppose, then, that you want to serve that web-app, so that people can see and use it. In order to do that, you must perform some boilerplate:

1. Create an `index.js` file which imports your class and injects it into the DOM;
2. Minify that JavaScript file into a `index.min.js` file;
3. Create an HTML with proper headers, which includes the minified JS;
4. Pack those two files into a `public` directory;
5. Run some HTTP library to serve that `public` directory.

Those tasks aren't hard, but are certainly repetitive and common enough for me to wonder, is there any utility on the React library that performs those steps? I.e., something like:

```
React.serveDefaultApp(myWebApp, 7171);
```

Comment: Note: I'm not sure this question is appropriate, but where else would I learn if such a thing already exists, in order to avoid reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Not familiar with this area, but I'm assuming you've searched relevant documentation, right?

Comment: Obviously, also asked on IRC where nobody knows...